# Is there a way to use box-sizing:border box without fixing width?

Tags: html, css

So I have the next scenario, I'm creating a button and it's height will be always 56px but it's width is relative to it's content, so if the inner text is large the button will also be larger and so on...
The thing is that the button on it's normal state has no border but on hover state it has a border of 2px and so the total height will be 60px. If i set the box-sizing property the height will be kept the same 56px as i want but the width keeps getting bigger because i can't set a fixed dimension since it's relative to the inner text!
So my css for example:

```
    height: 56px;
    width: fit-content;
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Is there a way to make the box-sizing work with no fixed width in pixels?

Comment: Can you add html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the colored border is only applies on `:hover` then apply a **transparent border** on the unhovered state and the size will always remain the same.

```css
button {
  height: 56px;
  width: fit-content;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

button:hover {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button>Lorem</button>

<button>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</button>
```